# Take values from a list of strings(python)

Tags: python

If I have a list of several strings in python, and each of these strings contains a value. How can I take those values and print them to a list?  Example: the string might be "abc def g T = 5 hij". All the strings will be the same except the number.

Comment: "All the strings will be the same except the number"? Why? What's different about it, and what should it turn into? Please describe what the resulting list should look like. Right now, this is much too vague.

Comment: I have hundreds of strings that look exactly the same except the number that comes right after 'T =' I just need a list of numbers as an out put.

Comment: 0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7 something like this

Comment: Is the value you want guaranteed to be the only number in the string?

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions. Assuming your list of strings is called `items`:

```
result = [int(re.search(r'\d+', x).group(0)) for x in items]
```

If the value isn't guaranteed to be the only number in the string, just make the regular expression more specific; say,

```
re.search(r'T = (\d+)', x).group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

### One Approach

Use the `split()` method on a string to split it into a list.

```
newList = "abc def g T = 5 hij".split()
```

If you need to split on something other than spaces, add in an argument to `split()`. Eg,

```
"abc def g T = 5 hij".split("=")[1]
```

splits the string on an equals sign.

So from what I understand of your situation, something like this should do the trick:

```
listOfVals = [valStr.split("=")[1] for valStr in strList]
```

where `listOfVals` is the output list and `strList` is the "list of several strings."

### Notes

I should note that this only works for strings where the data you want is between the first and second `=`s, however I don't really know the specifics of your strings. This should give you an idea of how to approach the problem though.